# Every metric $\delta$ on sets is $\delta (A, B) = \mu(A \Delta B)$, resp. $\delta(A, B) = \mu(A \Delta B)/\mu (A \cup B)$, for some measure $\mu$?

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces

Suppose $\mu$ is a measure and that  $\delta (A, B) = \mu(A \Delta B)$ (where $\Delta$ represents symmetric difference, and $A=B$ whenever $\mu(A \Delta B) = 0$). Then $\delta$ is a distance function.

My question is about the converse: supposing that $\delta$ is a distance function on a family of sets, is there a measure $\mu$ such that $\delta (A, B) = \mu(A \Delta B)$?

Likewise, supposing $\gamma$ is a distance function, is there a measure $\mu$ such that $\gamma(A, B) = \dfrac{\mu(A \Delta B)}{\mu (A \cup B)}$?

Comment: Two remarks: 1) You are dealing with distances in the set of subsets of a certain "ambiant" space; 2) I don't think ultrametric distances can be derived in this way.

Comment: Tons of distances are such that no $\mu$ exists. For example, a needed condition is that, for every $(A,B,C)$, $\delta(A\cup C,B\cup C)=\delta(A,B)$.

Comment: Is that also a sufficient condition?